# background tableview ios

Tags: ios, user-interface, custom-controls, tableview

http://rghost.net/41831486.view

I need to make this custom interface for UItableView, but if i use this code below i'm having a terrible results, the picture that i use as a background is showing itself in each cell. I need a sample code, help me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]]];


    [self fetchAudios];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

Comment: what your question is basically ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
UIImageView *ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[ImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];

self.tableView.backgroundView = ImageView;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider just making the tableview a subview to your viewcontroller, adding an imageview behind it while making the background of your tableview to be clear.

Comment: Explain for idiot please. Because i going to delete tableview controller from story board and make view controller.

Comment: Ok. You are on the right track. You want to make it a view controller and add a UIImageView to that as the background. You then add a tableView on top of that and ensure that the tableview's "dataSource" and "delegate" are set to the owning viewcontroller (also in its header set it as the delegate and data source: <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: Then implement the same delegate and data source methods in that view controller and you should be golden. This is a slightly outdated post I wrote about it but it still applies and could help you: http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/06/30/iphone-dev-building-a-custom-tableview-with-a-background-image-and-separate-button/

Comment: Oh, I will try. Tnx for help.